# Get root record source from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I need to find the root source source for all the record using SQL. Below is the table structure and example.

| CustID | CertNo | OldCertNo | Source | Root Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CU1 | C1 |  | Digital | Digital |
| CU1 | C2 | C1 | NON | Digital |
| CU1 | C3 | C2 | NON | Digital |

Lead and lag will not be able to give the correct details because for 1 user there can be 3 record for other there can be 10 record.

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result. (I.e. a [mcve].)

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_, not records.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive CTE to get the root cert:

```sql
WITH data AS (
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    VALUES  (N'CU1', N'C1', N'', N'Digital')
    ,   (N'CU1', N'C2', N'C1', N'NON')
    ,   (N'CU1', N'C3', N'C2', N'NON')
    ,   (N'CU1', N'C4', N'C3', N'Bzz')
) t (CustID,CertNo,OldCertNo,Source)
)
, rootdata AS (
SELECT  custid, certno AS root, certno,  source, source AS rootsource
FROM    data
WHERE   oldcertno = '' -- start at the root
UNION ALL
SELECT  c.custid, c.certno AS root, c2.certno, c2.source, c.rootsource -- forward original root source cert
FROM    rootdata c
INNER JOIN data c2
 ON c2.custid = c.custid
 AND    c2.oldcertno = c.certno -- join on parent cert
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM   rootdata
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

This forwards root cert source to each of the children certs.

Comment: this is working fine and thank you so much. I want to understand how it works and what is the logic behind.